# Работа функции setOnMouseDragEntered в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется код:

```
Pane box = new Pane();
box.setPrefSize(100, 100);
box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #3E938B;");
box.setOnMouseDragged(event-> {
    box.relocate(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
});


Pane notbox = new Pane();
notbox.setPrefSize(100, 100);
notbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");
notbox.relocate(200, 200);
notbox.setOnMouseDragEntered(event-> {
    System.exit(0);
});
```

По логике, при перетаскивании `box` на `notbox` должно выполняться прописанное в `setOnMouseDragEntered`действие, но, почему-то, ничего не происходит. Объясните, почему ивент не срабатывает? В чем моя ошибка? Какая логика работы у данных ивентов?

Comment: А что получится если использовать `setOnMouseDragOver`?

Comment: @defaultlocale так же - никакого результата

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы setOnMouseDragEntered сработало, необходимо запустить полный жест перетаскивания("press-drag-release") - startFullDrag().

```
Pane box = new Pane();
box.setPrefSize(100, 100);
box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #3E938B;");
box.setOnMouseDragged(event-> {
    box.relocate(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
});
box.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
    box.startFullDrag();
});


Pane notbox = new Pane();
notbox.setPrefSize(100, 100);
notbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");
notbox.relocate(200, 200);
notbox.setOnMouseDragEntered(event-> {
    System.exit(0);
});
```